# How to split the toc in two?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc, minitoc

I want to split my thesis in two main parts: "Theory" and "Practice" in such a way that:

1) "Theory" and "Practice" appear as main bookmarks in the pdf;

2) the table of contests is splitted in two, so that in the pdf you see:

Theory

Table of contests (Theory)

...

Practice

Table of contests (Practice)

Use the code below.

```
    \begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    \title{Title}

    \maketitle

    % Here I want to place "Theory" that appears as a bookmark and it is placed in the pdf
    % before the first toc and embrace all the parts below up except "Practice"

    % Here I want to place the toc of "Theory"

    \mainmatter

    \chapter*{Preface\label{SecPreface}}

    \markboth{Preface}{Preface}

    %TCIMACRO{%
    %\TeXButton{AddToTableOfContents}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}}}%
    %BeginExpansion
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}%
    %EndExpansion

    \part{Part 1}

    \part{Part 2}

    \part{Part 3}

    %TCIMACRO{%
    %\TeXButton{settings TOC}{\cleardoublepage
    %\phantomsection
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Bibliography}} }%
    %BeginExpansion
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Bibliography}
    %EndExpansion
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{finance}

    %TCIMACRO{%
    %\TeXButton{settings TOC}{\cleardoublepage
    %\phantomsection
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{List of Figures}} }%
    %BeginExpansion
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{List of Figures}
    %EndExpansion
    %TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{List of Figures}{\listoffigures}}%
    %BeginExpansion
    \listoffigures%
    %EndExpansion

    \chapter*{Notation}

    \markboth{Notation}{Notation}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Notation}

    \bookmarksetup{startatroot}

    % Here I want to place "Practice" that appears as a bookmark and it is placed in the pdf
    % before the second toc and embrace all the parts below 

    % Here I want to place the toc of "Practice"

    \part{Case study 1}

    \part{Case study 2}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal working example, so that we can figure more about your document structure.
But you can probably have a look at the `minitoc`package.

Comment: You have already answers to any of your questions, please consider to accept one of them each

Answer (score 3):

Here is the follow-up code from the previous question by the O.P., with `\superparts` etc.

There is a new `\localtableofcontents` which must be used **after** `\superpart`. Of course, there are some configuration like `\localcontentsname` to be added.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcounter{superpart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\superpart@@tocname}[1]{%
  \arabic{#1}toc%
}

\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
  \addcontentsline{\superpart@@tocname{superpart}}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
}{\typeout{Patched @part}}{}


\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{% 
    \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{% 
    \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
  \addcontentsline{\superpart@@tocname{superpart}}{chapter}{%
    \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{\typeout{Patched chapter}}{}

\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
  \addcontentsline{\superpart@@tocname{superpart}}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
}{\typeout{Patched @sect}}{}


% This is the standard latex kernel \@starttoc, it's not necessary if `book.cls` is used, but for `memoir.cls` etc. 
\def\latex@starttoc#1{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \@input{\jobname.#1}%
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup
}



\newcommand{\localtableofcontents}{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \latex@starttoc{\superpart@@tocname{superpart}}% 
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\superpart}{om}{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \refstepcounter{superpart}%
  \phantomsection%
  \hypertarget{superpart::\number\value{superpart}}{}%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \bookmark[startatroot,level=-2,bold,color=red,dest=superpart::\number\value{superpart}]{#1}%
  }{%
    \bookmark[startatroot,level=-2,bold,color=red,dest=superpart::\number\value{superpart}]{#2}%
  }%
}



\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\begin{document}

\superpart{Theory}
\localtableofcontents 
\part{Number One}
\chapter{First chapter}
\part{Number Two}

\chapter{Second chapter}



\superpart{Practice}
\localtableofcontents
\part{Number Three}
\chapter{Three}
\part{Number Four}
\chapter{Four}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is two solutions:

**with minitoc package**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}‎‎
\doparttoc

\part{Theory}
\renewcommand{\ptctitle}{\contentsname\ (Theory)}
\parttoc
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\part{Practice}
\renewcommand{\ptctitle}{\contentsname\ (Practice)}
\parttoc

\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

**with titletoc (titlesec) package (Updated)**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


%---------------- Theory part
\part*{Theory}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Theory}
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{-1}{%
       \chapter*{\contentsname\ (Theory)}%
       \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname\ (Theory)}}%
                {\MakeUppercase{\contentsname\ (Theory)}}}
%----------------

\part{Firstst theory test}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\part{Last theory test}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument


%---------------- Practice part
\stopcontents
\part*{Practice}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Practice}
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{-1}{%
       \chapter*{\contentsname\ (Practice)}%
       \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname\ (Practice)}}%
                {\MakeUppercase{\contentsname\ (Practice)}}}
%---------------- 

\part{Firstst practice test}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\part{Last practice test}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument


\stopcontents

\end{document}
```

**global toc**
[image]

**Theory toc**
[image]

Comment: Hi. the second solution is good. What about if "Theory" and "Practice" contain whole parts instead of chapters. Can we make them as "superparts"?

Comment: @Marcello of course you can but I think this is another question.

Comment: @Marcello: Please do not change the question from A to B, adding requests. touhami has made two nice propositions

Comment: The question was implicit in the comment: "Here I want to place "Theory" that appears as a bookmark and it is placed in the pdf before the first toc and embrace all the parts below up except "Practice"". This implicitly means that "Theory" had to contain \part{Part 1}, \part{Part 2} etc as I wrote in the code.

Comment: @Marcello well, what about Christian's answer, you can't accepte it? it's great huge work and you don't upvote it yet.

Comment: @Marcello I Updated the answer.

Comment: @touhami: I can't upvote again ;-)